# Reading console application output to webpage

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am working on a django app. I have a console application which displays some text. Its a bit of lengthy text based on some processes and this console application runs for about 5 to 10 minutes.

I want to capture that whole content to django website. I Explored various web articles but couldn't get a solid idea on how to achieve this.

If i use subprocess.check_output to run that application and then display results , it will be too late.

I know , i need to use Ajax. But not sure how to achieve this.

I tried , redirecting the output of the console application to a text file. I tried using the ajax to read it , based on the content. Its not working. Is there an efficient way of doing this ??

i used the below code to read from text. To be honest, i dono Ajax or java script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function addmsg(type, msg){
    /* Simple helper to add a div.
    type is the name of a CSS class (old/new/error).
    msg is the contents of the div */
    $("#messages").append(
        "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
    );
}

function waitForMsg(){
    /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
    When it complete (or errors)*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/path/to/text/file/",

        async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

        success: function(data){ /* called when request to barge.php completes */
            addmsg("new", data); /* Add response to a .msg div (with the "new" class)*/

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
});
</script>
<div class="msg"></div>
```

Please help me how to solve this problem.

THanks.

Comment: [this](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/Comet) exactly does what you describe

Comment: Looks similar. Let me go through it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: just note the line which says `while not process.poll():` should in fact be `while process.poll() is None:`, otherwise in some cases it will not terminate.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution.

in the view, i create a thread and spawn the console application which runs for 5 - 10 min.
Then i serve a page with the above ajax code, which will read the output text file as and when the text file is getting updated.

Thanks,
Bala.